# run Powershell commands as admin to multiple computers

Tags: powershell, dns

I want to run these 2 powershell commands:

```
$Array = Get-DnsClientServerAddress;
foreach($element in $Array) { 
  Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex $($element).InterfaceIndex -ServerAddress 10.128.162.216
};
```

to multiple clients through a domain policy in order to change dns server, but they have to be executed as administrator. I found something like "Start-Process powershell...", but I do not know how to combine this with commands above.

Also, I want to ask if there is a similar command to update the SECONDARY dns setting.

Comment: Have you tried running Powershell as an Administration and executing your commands?

Comment: right click the PS shortcut and select Run 
As Admin.

Answer (score 0):

Just search for "How to apply PowerShell script using group policy"

To set DNS servers you should use the DNSServerSearchOrder property of the local NIC instance:

```
# New DNS servers, in order
$NewDNS= @{'192.168.1.1','192.168.1.2'}

# Ensure that this variable ONLY contains the required NIC, by using filters
$NIC = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter 'IPEnabled=True' # Use Where-Object here to filter further if required

Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $NIC -MethodName SetDNSServerSearchOrder -Arguments $NewDNS
```